# How do I print Optional Int in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, option-type

I simply want to Print the optional humidityPercentage component of weather to the console.

```
let cityName: String
var humidityPercentage: Int? 
var temperatureCentigrade: Int?

var weather = (weather.cityName= "GR", weather.humidityPercentage = 2, 
weather.temperatureCentigrade = 2)

if let weather.humidityPercentage = weather.humidityPercentage {
  print(weather.humidityPercentage)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya syntax is borked. Keep learning the syntax.

```swift
let weather = (
  cityName: "GR",
  humidityPercentage: 2 as Optional,
  temperatureCentigrade: 2
)

if let humidityPercentage = weather.humidityPercentage {
  print(humidityPercentage)
}
```

Comment: Why the `as Optional?`

Comment: Because otherwise it's an `Int`, not an `Int?`, and therefore, can't be unwrapped.

Comment: Oh I thought you were initing a `Weather` object, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `.` in the constant. Try this instead:

```
if let percentage = weather.humidityPercentage {
  print(percentage)
}
```